# React-query mutation isError not setting true on failed POST

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch, expo, react-query

I am using the following fetch post request to create an item in my DB. I am trying to use react-query to detect the error thrown by the request.

```
export function createItem(id, body, token) {
  fetch(`${API_URL}/${id}/items`, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}` },
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
  })
    .then(res => {
      if (res.ok) {
        return res.json()
      }

      console.log(res.status)

      throw new Error("Error creating review")
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
}
```

I have the mutation set like so:

```
const mutation = useMutation(() => {
    return createItem(props.item.id, item, token)
})
```

And its called with:

```
<Button disabled={!valid} onPress={() => mutation.mutate()}>
    Submit
</Button>
```

I use this logic to display the error:

```
{
   mutation.isError && <Text>{mutation.error.message}</Text>
}
```

I see the `createItem` function errors with a 400 status code which is what I expect but react-query does not set `isError` to true. Instead `isSuccess` is true. Am I handling the error wrong some how?

Answer (score 3):

From the [react query docs](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/mutations), they return a promise to the mutation, so try to change your function `createItem` to the following:

```
export function createItem(id, body, token) {
  // return the fetch as a promise
  return fetch(`${API_URL}/${id}/items`, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}` },
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
  })
  // remove then and catch here
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are catching the error inside the mutation function. React Query requires to you to return a resolved or rejected promise from your function.

[Promise.catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) also returns a Promise. If you don't return anything, it will be a Promise that returns `undefined`. But that is still a resolved Promise that will be passed to React Query.

So, in short: Don't catch inside the function. Use one of the callbacks that react-query provides for error logging:

```
export function createItem(id, body, token) {
  fetch(`${API_URL}/${id}/items`, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}` },
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
  })
    .then(res => {
      if (res.ok) {
        return res.json()
      }

      console.log(res.status)

      throw new Error("Error creating review")
    })
}
```

```
const mutation = useMutation(
  () => {
    return createItem(props.item.id, item, token)
  },
  {
    onError: (error) => console.log(error)
  }
)
```